# Adding new column to MySQL using existing Python Pandas data

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, data-structures

I'm trying to append a new column to a MySQL table using existing Pandas data from Python.

For example, if I have a table in MySQL with 2 columns and 1000 rows, and I also have a Pandas dataframe in Python with 1 column and 1000 rows, each corresponding to its equivalent row in the MySQL table, how can I append this Pandas data onto the MySQL table as column 3?

I know I can add the new column using the following code:

```
my_cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE example_table ADD column_3 INT(15)")
```

This will add column 3 to the MySQL table with all 'NULL' values, however I cannot find a way to populate this with my existing Pandas data.

I have tried the following but it only seems to allow you to input individual integers or strings, rather than an array of values like I've attempted here with my 'pandas_data' dataframe:

```
my_cursor.execute("UPDATE example_table SET column_3 = pandas_data")
mydb.commit()
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *each corresponding to its equivalent row in the MySQL table* This is impossible for 1-column data. If this column defines the relation to another table (what row in the table matches to what row in another table) then there is no data to be added in this row. If this column contains data to be added then there is no relation information - noway to determine which row of second table each particular value must be added into.

Comment: I don’t think I explained myself well so I’ll rephrase. Imagine I import the 2 columns from MySQL into a pandas data frame, then create a new column 3 in this data frame which is just the average of the two values in each row of columns 1 and 2. Therefore column 3 will be the same length as columns 1 and 2. I then want to write this new column back to MySQL into the table (append column 3 on beside column 2) without re-writing columns 1 and 2 as well. 
 
Of course I could just overwrite the whole table in MySQL with all 3 columns but that seems computationally inefficient.

Comment: For 1000 rows truncate then save new data is optimal I think.